# Why php exec() fails .tex→xelatex→.pdf, but succeed .tex→xelatex→.xdv→xdvipdfmx→.pdf?

Tags: php, system-calls, xetex

The call of command:

```
$dir = "/path/to/source/file";
exec("cd $dir;xelatex filesource.tex", $output_array[0]);
```

always fails, but:

```
$dir = "/path/to/source/file";
exec("cd $dir;/usr/texbin/xelatex -no-pdf filesource.tex", $output_array[0]);// now we have .xdv file
exec("cd $dir;/usr/texbin/xdvipdfmx filesource.xdv", $output_array[1]);
```

succeed, and result .pdf file absolutely valid. What is the trick?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with PHP or system calls, and everything to do with LaTeX. I suggest you ask on [tex.se]

Comment: It's not a pure latex question, because it's a question about system call of user _www a command with unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

xelatex needs its "helpers" e.g xdvipdfmx executable to be in the PATH of the PHP environment